# windows phone webbrowser control file download

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a file hosted in a secured site (https), so I use the web browser control to pass the URL and the headers for authentication. Can the WebBrowser control render the document/pdf files just like the phone native browser. Even the public document(not secure) are not rendering. Does the webbrowser control similar to the native phone IE when it comes to file download?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to open a PDF from a web location you'll have to do:

```
new WebBrowserTask 
    { 
        Uri = new Uri("http://path.to/file.pdf", UriKind.Absolute)
    }.Show();
```

This depends on the user having the Adobe, PDF viewer app installed on their phone. There's no way to show a PDF document within the WebBrowser control.